# any storage service like amazon s3 which allows upload /Download at the same time on large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

My requirement to upload large file (35gb), when the upload is in progress need to start the download process on the same file. Any storage service which allows develop .net application

Because Amazon s3 will not allow simultaneously upload and download on

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft Azure Storage Page or Append Blobs to solve this:

1) Begin uploading the large data
2) Concurrently download small ranges of data (no greater than 4MB so the client library can read it in one chunk) that have already been written to.

Page Blobs need to be 512 byte aligned and can be read and written to in a random access pattern, whereas AppendBlobs need to be written to sequentially in an append-only pattern.

As long as you're reading sections that have already been written to you should have no problems. Check out the Blob Getting Started Doc: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/ and some info about Blob Types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee691964.aspx

And feel free to contact us with any follow up questions.